# JNDI lookup failed on GlassFish 5

Tags: java, ejb, jndi, enterprise

I'm new with Java EE and my problem may seems stupid.

I have `javax.naming.NameNotFoundException` when I'm trying to deploy my application on Glassfish. It happens when I'm implementing java.util.Observer in the DeviceStorage class. When I don't it deploys without any error. Anybody has an idea why it may happens?

```
Exception while deploying the app [Test-1.0-SNAPSHOT] : JNDI lookup 
failed for the resource: Name: 
[java:module/env/com.view.servlet.TestServlet/deviceStorage], Lookup: 
[com.core.DeviceStorage#com.core.DeviceStorage], Type: [Session].

Caused by: 
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: 
com.core.DeviceStorage#com.core.DeviceStorage not found
```

```java
@Singleton
public class ServersStateListener extends Observable {
...
}
```

```java
@Singleton
public class DeviceStorage implements Observer{
...
}
```

```java
@WebServlet("/test")
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @EJB
    private ServersStateListener serversStateListener;

    @EJB
    private DeviceStorage deviceStorage;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("--== Servlet ==--");

        System.out.printf("ServerStateListener: %s\n", serversStateListener);
        System.out.printf("DeviceStorage: %s\n", deviceStorage);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug in GlassFish that caused error messages like that. The bug was found and fixed in Payara (which is derived from GlassFish) in February 2018 and included in release version 5.182. I don't know if it was fixed in GlassFish. The Payara bug report can be found [here](https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues/2430), and the fix was committed [here](https://github.com/payara/Payara/pull/2445).

The bug report mentions that the following property (JVM option) can be used as a work-around:

`-Ddeployment.resource.validation=false`

I'm not sure if that setting works with GlassFish, too, or if it's specific to Payara. But it's certainly worth a try.